# Scaldi - binding to single/multiple instances

Tags: scala, scaldi

I recently switched from SubCut to Scaldi and there's a feature I find undocumented/missing:

In SubCut, when you define a binding, you can [choose between different binding modes](https://github.com/dickwall/subcut/blob/master/GettingStarted.md#setting-up-a-configuration-module) - `toSingle`, `toProvider`, `to moduleInstanceOf`, `toModuleSingle`, which decide if the injected instances will be created once, or each time the bind is performed. I don't see the analogous behaviours explicitly defined in the [Scaldi documentation](http://scaldi.github.io/scaldi/Scaldi.html), so I would like to make sure I understand how the different behaviours can be achieved in Scaldi:

By default the `to` method is lazy and creates the injected instance the first time it's "requested". There's a `toNonLazy` in [the api](http://scaldi.github.io/scaldi/api/index.html#scaldi.BindHelper) which I guess creates the instance even before the first time it's "requested". And there's a `toProvider`, which in the following example...

```
bind [Widget] toProvider new ParticularWidget()
```

...would create a new `ParticularWidget` every time it is injected in an `Injectable`.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it  works exactly as you described. If binding is defined with `toProvider`, then inject will always create new instances.

You can see its behavior in action in this spec:

https://github.com/scaldi/scaldi/blob/master/src/test/scala/scaldi/WordBinderSpec.scala#L100

---

#### Update

You can find more info in the documentation:

http://scaldi.org/learn/#define-bindings